# Alert correlation benchmark

Tags: ids

I'm looking for some alert correlation tool to reduce number of alerts about 50%. It should support IDMEF. I googled for alert correlation tools but just found ACARM-ng, TIAA and MACE and all of them are free or open source.
Is there any commercial tool or some benchmark I could use?

Comment: Tool recommendations are discouraged on this forum. However, any Security Information Event Management (SIEM) should be able to do what you are looking for. IBM QRadar, HP Arcsight, RSA enVision etc are a few on top of my head but you do research on your own which one is best for you.